# Using PHP how to echo content every certain amount of time?

Tags: php, buffer

Code:

```
echo "1";
sleep(1);

echo "2";
sleep(1);

echo "3";
```

What am trying to do is have the script echo "1" in the screen wait for one second then display "2" etc... As is the script waits for 2 seconds then displays all content at one.  All i know about this is that it has do to with buffering

Comment: @Babiker - is not doable for web page contents (that is not the way HTTP works for PHP). However, suggestion suggested by @netcoder will work for CLI

Comment: @ajreal: Thanks for the reply, this did work for me before i just forgot how to do it.

Comment: @Babiker - oh, with this, it simply mean the content only will display on user browser after X seconds, this is really what you after for ?

Comment: @ajreal: Yes, i do understand that one request will be made.

Comment: @Babiker - alright, then , sorry for being paranoid

Comment: @ajreal: No, i appreciate your help.

Comment: @ajreal: It is also possible in most browsers. However, Chrome has a known issue about flushing not working correctly. It works in Firefox though, and OP is using Chrome apparently.

Comment: You can try setting `output_buffering = off` and `implicit_flush = On` in your ini file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable output buffering by flushing at the beginning of script, and activate implicit output buffer flushing. This should do it:

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
   echo $i.'<br>';
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: This script waits for 5 seconds than echo's all at once.

Comment: No it doesn't. What browser are you using?

Comment: @netcoder - You forgot to `ob_flush();` after you `sleep(1);`.

Comment: @andre: No. The reason I use [ob_implicit_flush](http://php.net/ob_implicit_flush) is to avoid flushing manually after each output.

Comment: @Babiker: There are known problems with flushing in Chrome. A simple Google Search for "output buffer chrome" and you will see what I mean. [Here is an example.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2e38f373a65be8a8&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ob_start();` to catpure the output in combination with `ob_flush(); flush();` to send it out to the browser, periodically.

So your example would become:

```
ob_start();
echo "1";
ob_flush(); flush();
sleep(1);

echo "2";
ob_flush(); flush();
sleep(1);

// ...
```

Comment: How would this look with my example?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the classy way to do something like this. These kind of stuff needs to be done in client side with javascript not server side with php.

Comment: Yes, i do agree.  I don't plan on rolling this out, I am merely experimenting